# How can I generate a comma-separated string in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I am trying to create comma separated string. e.g. abc,pqr,xyz
I am parsing the xml and want to generate the comma separated string of the values of nodes in xml.

I am doing the following:

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Column"])
      NSString *strTableColumn = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"value"];
```

I am getting different nodes value in `strTableColumn` while parsing and want to generate comma separated of this. Please help.

Comment: are these values  seperated by space? or one time only one value comes in strTableColumn variable?

Comment: You should accept answers by pressing the tick button. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5645211/377384) looks good.

Answer (score 23):

I would do to it like this. Before you start your XML processing, create a mutable array to hold each "Column" value (probably want this to be an iVar in your parser class):

```
NSMutableArray *columns = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Then parse the XML, adding each string to the array:

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Column"]) {
    [columns addObject:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"value"]];
}
```

When you're done, create the comma-separated string and release the array:

```
NSString *strTableColumn = [columns componentsJoinedByString:@","];
[columns release];
columns = nil;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following code:

```
NSString *timeCreated = elementName;  
NSArray *timeArray = [timeCreated componentsSeparatedByString:@","];        
NSString *t = [timeArray objectAtIndex:0];  
NSString *t1 = [timeArray objectAtindex:1];
```

Then append one by one string.

Comment: u r new to stack overflow...if u really like my answer then click check the answer....

Comment: "u r new to stack overflow...if u really like my answer then click check the answer". @Hiren bhadreshwara, SO encourages you to write using complete words. This isn't Twitter or a text message.

Answer (score 1):

use NSMutableString

then you can use

```
[yourMutableString appendString:@","];//there is a comma
[yourMutableString appendString:someOtherString];
```

in this way your strings are separated by comma

Answer (score 0):

This method will return you the nsmutablestring with comma separated values from an array

```
-(NSMutableString *)strMutableFromArray:(NSMutableArray *)arr withSeperater:(NSString *)saperator 
{ 
    NSMutableString *strResult = [NSMutableString string];

    for (int j=0; j<[arr count]; j++)
{
    NSString *strBar = [arr objectAtIndex:j];
    [strResult appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strBar]];
    if (j != [arr count]-1)
    {
        [strResult appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",seperator]];
    }
}
return strResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thought can be that you parse the data and append commas using the NSString append methods. But that can have extra checks. So better solution is to

**Parse data -> Store into array -> Add comma separators -> Finally store in string**

```
// Parse data -> Store into array
NSMutableArray *arrayOfColumns = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Column"]){
   [arrayOfColumns addObject:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"value"]];
}
// Add comma separators -> Finally store in string
NSString *strTableColumn = [arrayOfColumns componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```